# Wordpress ajax WP_Query

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, variables

I'm trying to load post with ajax using a variable to get posts by year. I've found this great tutorial https://www.creare.co.uk/blog/simple-wp_query-ajax and I'm trying to modify it to my needs but I have 0 experience with Ajax and not so much with jquery...

this is my modified code but the year is not passed and I don't know how to do it, I appreciate any help

js

```js
//If input is changed, load posts
$('#genre-filter input').live('change', function(){
    genre_get_posts(); //Load Posts
});

//Find Selected Genres
function getSelectedGenres()
{
    var genres = [];

    $("#genre-filter div").click(function() {
        var genres = $(this).attr('value');
        console.log(genres);
    });        

    return genres;
}

//Main ajax function
function genre_get_posts(paged)
{

    var ajax_url = ajax_genre_params.ajax_url;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: ajax_url,
        data: {
            action: 'genre_filter',
            genres: getSelectedGenres,

        },
        beforeSend: function ()
        {
            //Show loader here
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            //Hide loader here
            $('#genre-results').html(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            $("#genre-results").html('<p>There has been an error</p>');
        }
    });                
}
```

template

```html
<section id="primary" class="content-area">
<div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">
    <?php
    if ( have_posts() ):
        while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content' );
    endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <div id="genre-filter">
            <div id="2018" value="2018" name="filter_genre[]">2018</div>
            <div id="2017" value="2017" name="filter_genre[]">2017</div>
      </div>
        <div id="genre-results"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

functions.php

```php
function ajax_genre_filter() {
    $query_data = $_GET;
    $genre_terms = ( $query_data[ 'genres' ] ) ? explode( ',', $query_data[ 'genres' ] ) : false;
    $book_args = array(
        'post_type' => 'book',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        'year' => $genre_terms,
    );
    $book_loop = new WP_Query( $book_args );

    if ( $book_loop->have_posts() ):
        while ( $book_loop->have_posts() ): $book_loop->the_post();
            get_template_part( 'content' );
        endwhile;
        echo $query_data;
    else :
        get_template_part( 'content-none' );
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    die();
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant error messages within your question, Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is variable scoping in `getSelectedGenres`. I would imaging you're always getting an empty array due to the 2nd `var` in your event handler. Try the modified version below.

```
function getSelectedGenres()
{
  var genres = [];

  $("#genre-filter div").click(function() {
    var g = $(this).attr('value');
    genres.push(g);
    console.log(g);
  });        

  return genres;
}
```

Additionally, it looks like `ajax_genre_filter` reads the year from the genres query string `genres` based on the mapping `'year' => $genre_terms` so try including the selected year in your function `getSelectedGenres`.

Comment: Hi Babak,
thanks for the answer. I've found were was the problem. When i've changed inputs into div's ajax was not executed so i've changed them into ratios and now it's working. One more change in funcions.php was needed to do and now everything is working as i wanted.
'year' => $query_data['genres'],